# Google Cloud Function to run same training job with different user args in paralell

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm trying to find a way to run the same training job with different user arguments in parallel.
I need to run MYMODULE for each one of the product_X in parallel. MYMODULE reads user_arg, but I need that each time it reads it, it reads a different product, and to launch them in parallel.I know one solution could be run three blocks of training code separately, but maybe there's a function to do it directly with one.

```
!gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training demo_training_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") \
    --staging-bucket gs: MYBUCKET\
    --package-path MYPATH \
    --module-name MYMODULE \
    --region MYREGION \
    --runtime-version=2.1 \
    --python-version=3.7 \
    --scale-tier BASIC \
    -- \
    --model-bucket MYBUCKET \
    --output-dir MYDIR \
    --user_arg product_1, product_2, product_3 \
```

MYMODULE looks like this, and I need to read a different product on each run.

```
def train_and_evaluate (args):
    ...code

    product = args.user_arg

    ...more code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't client library for this type of call. But, at google, all is API. Therefore, you can perform a direct API call to run your jobs.

You can call the [AI Platform job creation API](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/create) to create your job. You need to specify a [training job body](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#Job) and in it you have a [training job input](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#TrainingInput). In this object, you have the list of `args` that you provide to your training job.

If you want an example of the JSON to populate, run your gcloud command with the option `--log-http` and the API call will be printed on the console.

---

When you perform your API call, you need to perform and authenticated call. You can use the [Google OAuth2 library](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files) to get the credential. Then, generate an access token that you add as `Authorization: Bearer` header. Don't forget also to add the `content-type` in the header (as `application/json` of course)